# When didDeselect a Custom Cell the image doesn't change on iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, checkbox, uiimage

Im working with a `UITableView` that has a Custom Cell. The Custom Cell only has a Label and a `UIImage`, the `UIImage` will be used as a checkbox.

So the problem is that once I click a row the checkbox image changes to a checkmark png image (which is ok) BUT once I click the same row again it doesnt diselect the row, the function `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` runs , i set some `NSLogs` to check on that BUT the image is not changed to uncheckbox and the background color doesnt change.

I feel its because the tableview its not been refreshed

The funny thing here is that if I dont use the custom cell and I only use the accessoryType to none or checkmark (depending the case) it works.

Here is the code for the `viewDidLoad` were I just init some variable:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Let me select more than one row
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

//Used to store all the cells that were selected
      self.selectedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
```

I got 1 Section and 20 rows (later its going to be an array but thats no problem)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }


    cell.cellNameDrinkLabel.text = @"Cell";

    if ( [self.selectedIndexPaths indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound )
    {

        cell.cellCheckboxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uncheckbox.png"]];

    } else
    {
        cell.cellCheckboxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"checkbox.png"]];

    }



    return cell;
}
```

Here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellCheckboxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"checkbox.png"]];


    if(![self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);

}
```

And here is the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` function (the one i feel is the problem)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.cellCheckboxImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uncheckbox.png"]];

    [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: I've had this happen before, had to hack it in a horrible way using indexPathForVisibleRows to get it to work. Interested to see if there's a legit solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not you omit

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and try like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(![self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: If this helped you, Vote me up :P

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me, Hope it will work for you as well.

We can manage it in single method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tablecell *cell = (tablecell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    NSData *dataCheck = UIImagePNGRepresentation(checkImage);
    NSData *dataCheckCell = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cell.img.image);
    if ([dataCheckCell isEqualToData:dataCheck]) {
        cell.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you get block in above code. will help you to solve.

Answer (score 0):

u can do like this, there is no need to implement `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

u can try like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomeCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
   if(cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[CustomeCellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
   }
   if([selectedPaths containsObject:indexPath])
       cell.checkMarkImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
   else
       cell.checkMarkImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get the custom cell
    CustomeCellTableViewCell *cell = (CustomeCellTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell)
    {
        if([selectedPaths containsObject:indexPath])
        {
           [selectedPaths removeObject:indexPath];
           cell.checkMarkImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.jpg"];
        }
        else
        {
           [selectedPaths addObject:indexPath];
           cell.checkMarkImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
         }
   }
   //deselect the cell with animation
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```